# How to add addtional spatial data to 'qgis2threejs' programatically?

Tags: javascript, json, qgis2threejs

Is there a way to add additional data to the 3D model which exported from the 'qgis2threejs ' module?

For example, if I create lines (with X, Y, Z(height) coords) in PostGIS could I load it into the model somehow? (without exporting the model again)

I think the solution is in the'.json' files.